# Trino Container and Postgres Container Connector Configuration jdbc-url

Tags: postgresql, docker, jdbc, connector, trino

I would like to establish a connection between trino and postgres each running in a docker container using the postgresql-connector. I can't seem to finde the correct connection parameters for the jdbc-url.

I got trino and a postgres database running in docker:

```
docker run --name trino -d -p 8080:8080 -v $PWD/catalog:/etc/trino/catalog/ trinodb/trino
```

```
docker run -d --name my-postgres-db -p 5432:5432 -v /home/postgresdb/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data my-postgres-image
```

I mounted a postgresql.properties file to the trino container as described [here](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/postgresql.html):

```
connector.name=postgresql
connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://my-postgres-db:5432/<db-name>
connection-user=user_1
connection-password=password_1
```

It worked for a local postgres database but when I adjusted the connection-url for my postgres container postgresql was not listed as a catalog. How do I use the postgresql-connector to connect the trino and postgres containers?

Answer (score 1):

## Quick fix

In this situation, the simplest way to get Trino to connect to the DB is use `host.docker.internal` in the jdbc url, in your case by changing this line in the properties file:

```
connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/<db-name>
```

Note that it does not work reliably across all operating systems (I've had luck with MacOS).

See: [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

## A better way

The cleanest way would be to switch to use [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), which would make it all much simpler in many ways:

```yaml
services:
  my-postgres-db:
    image: my-postgres-image
    ports:
      - 5432: 5432
    volumes:
      - /home/postgresdb/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  trino:
    image: trinodb/trino
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./catalog:/etc/trino/catalog
```

Then, if you run then run `docker-compose up`, the two services will be stood up side by side and the database will be reachable using the original url in your config.